# What's the name for people with black hair?

Tags: single-word-requests

There are *blonde*, *brunette* and *redhead*. What's the name for people with black hair?

Comment: There may not be a noun for those with black hair, but there are certainly adjectives: [raven-haired](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/raven-haired), or someone with jet-black hair, if it is very dark.

Comment: blackhead​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Although there is some debate over this, the Oxford Dictionary [definition](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/brunette) of *brunette* is:

> *noun*: a woman or girl with dark brown hair.

This source also mentions that in the US, an alternate form of the word *brunette* is *brunet*. The Merriam-Webster [definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brunet) of *brunet* is:

> a person having brown or black hair and often a relatively dark complexion —spelled brunet when used of a boy or man and usually brunette when used of a girl or woman

Thus, *brunette* includes the range of hair colors from brown to black. There is no specific and separate term for someone with black hair. However, people have suggested the term [*noirette*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Noirette). Note, also, that although the term *brunette* includes those with black hair, not everyone may agree. Therefore, this is the official term for people with black hair but not necessarily the one used in everyday life.

Comment: Even *redhead* isn't really on a par with the other two. Everyone is either fair-haired (blonde), or dark-haired (every other shade, including red and black).

Comment: @Fublefingers - are you persecuting the gingers by refusing to recognise them? :-)

Comment: Wouldn't he actually be persecuting everyone, since only the blondes have a category all their own?

Comment: I've never heard noirette before, but I like it!

Comment: but noirette really means nothing in french

Comment: @Nikko - Neither does "Sacre Bleu", but we still use it. :-)

Comment: no, "sacre bleu" is a french expression. In french you could use "noiraud" and "noiraude" for someone who has black hair ( or black skin ). But nowadays it is mostly used to name black cows (really). Noiret/ette might have existed though, it's true.

Comment: @Rory Alsop Ah the good ol' souless...

Comment: "Redhead" is an undoubtedly English-derived term, where "blonde", "brunette" and (ostensibly) "noirette" are French. How about another butchery of the language of love: "rougette"? You could also use the gentler-sounding term "blanquette" for someone with gray/white hair.

Comment: Don't forget 'silver fox'.

Comment: The dictionary definition may include people with black hair but I'm not sure how many people understand or use the term in that sense. Happy to conciede that this may be regional thing.

Comment: The Merriam-Webster definition you quoted no longer includes black hair.  However further down the page they do reference the "English Language Learners Definition" which includes black hair. Also the Oxford link doesn't seem to work anymore

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would consider redheads blonde, actually, if I was forced to pick.

Answer (score 25):

"Raven haired" is an older term that still seems to be understood by most.

Comment: "Raven haired" certainly means "black haired", but I've seen it used only in novels, and only of people the author intends the readers to perceive as sexually attractive. It may really be an old term, but for some reason I think of it as modern but intended to sound old. I think its natural home is in a fantasy novel. It would look a little out of place anywhere else.

Answer (score 11):

A person who has black hair is generally called "black-haired".

Most people will understand.