# A word to describe the color of hair that is nearly jet-black, but slightly brown?

Tags: single-word-requests, colors

What is a word to describe the color of a person's hair whose hair is nearly jet-black, but slightly brown?

For what it's worth, the person whose hair I have in mind is female with long, straight hair.

Comment: We're really trying to avoid using this site for "single word requests." If you have a particularly *interesting* problem to solve, all we ask is that you put a bit of effort and research into the question. See: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests/1737#1737 or http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity

Comment: Even if on-topic, this is probably a duplicate: [people with black hair](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33969/whats-the-name-for-people-with-black-hair)

Comment: Vote Reopen : we clearly all have different ideas about what's interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *[brunette](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/brunette)* is a woman with dark brown hair. You can also use the word as an adjective.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a terrible portmanteau, I can offer you *brunoir*: *brunette* + *noir*.